# powershell ConvertTo-csv doubleQuotes position

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm using the below query to export few eventlog entries into a csv file.

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter';ID=1}| SELECT-Object @{l = 'TimeCreated'; e = {Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}},@{l = 'DayOfWeek'; e = {(Get-Date $_.TimeCreated).DayOfWeek}},ID,@{Name='Source'; e={'Source=EventLog'}},{'Message='+$_.MESSAGE}|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -Skip 1| Out-File -Append C:\LOGS\TIMELINE\TEMP.csv"
```

This is the output i'm getting now:

```
"2014-08-14 13:51:46","Thursday","1","Source=EventLog","Message=The system has resumed from sleep"
```

How can i modify the query so that my outout becomes:

```
"2014-08-14 13:51:46","Thursday","1",Source="EventLog",Message="The system has resumed from sleep
```

(Double quotes position change to enclose only values)
[Post processing the output file would be my last option... Would be nice if could do in powershell..]

Comment: What problem would this solve?

Comment: As I said on one of the last questions you posted like this, I think you would be better off saving this as a script (.PS1) and then calling the script with PowerShell rather than trying to run it all in-line.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Although I'm not as impressed with it as i think i made it more complex.

I have put some returns in your code since the single line is enourmous to scroll though

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter';ID=1}| 
    SELECT-Object @{l = 'TimeCreated'; e = {Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}},@{l = 'DayOfWeek'; e = {(Get-Date $_.TimeCreated).DayOfWeek}},ID,@{Name='Source'; e={'Source=EventLog'}},{'Message='+$_.MESSAGE}|
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -Skip 1| 
    # The part i have added
    %{($_ -split "," | %{
         If ($_.Contains("=")){
               ($_ -replace "`"") -replace "=(.*)",'="$1"'
         } else {$_ }}) -join ","} |
    # The end of my addition
    Out-File -Append C:\LOGS\TIMELINE\TEMP.csv"
```

For this chunk that i have added before the out file is working with `"2014-08-14 13:51:46","Thursday","1","Source=EventLog","Message=The system has resumed from sleep"` that would get send to Out-File.

What I do with it is split the string back from the single line and process each element individually. Each line that contains an equals `=` sign I first remove all quotes. Then similar to Mad's expample I take everything after the equals sign and put quotes around it. Then before it gets sent to the file join it again with `,` so that it acts like a csv entry.

I know this can be improved but i can get proper output from the OP's `Get-WMIEvent` so  I cant make this more efficient without risky the current code.

**based on comment**

Try just inserting this part of the code into your existing statement just before the outfile.

```
%{($_ -split "," | %{If ($_.Contains("=")){($_ -replace "`"") -replace "=(.*)",'="$1"'} else {$_ }}) -join ","}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Needs some more escaping ? Error `'Out-File' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: I had the pipe at the beginning of the line it should be at the end. I have updated the answer. Also i think you need to remove all the returns i added for this work from command / run line.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. I added a ForEach loop near the end to replace `","<text>=` with `",<text>="`

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter';ID=1}| SELECT-Object @{l = 'TimeCreated'; e = {Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}},@{l = 'DayOfWeek'; e = {(Get-Date $_.TimeCreated).DayOfWeek}},ID,@{Name='Source'; e={'Source=EventLog'}},{'Message='+$_.MESSAGE}|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -Skip 1| %{$_ -replace "`",`"(\w+?=)", "`",`$1`""} | Out-File -Append C:\LOGS\TIMELINE\TEMP.csv"
```

**Edit:** I was missing quotes after the `=)`. Original ForEach loop:

```
%{$_ -replace "`",`"(\w+?=), "`",`$1`""}
```

Corrected:

```
%{$_ -replace "`",`"(\w+?=)", "`",`$1`""}
```

**Edit2:** If that is erroring you can use single quotes to enclose the arguments. It would look like:

```
%{$_ -replace '","(\w+?\=)', '",$1"'}
```

That removes any need for escaped characters.

**Edit3:** Please try this and see if it provides the desired output:

```
powershell -command "& {Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter';ID=1}| ForEach{'""{0}"",""{1}"",""{2}"",Source=""EventLog"",Message=""{3}""' -f (Get-Date $_.TimeCreated -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), ((Get-Date $_.TimeCreated).DayOfWeek), $_.ID, ($_.MESSAGE -join ',')}| Out-File -Append C:\temp\TEMP.csv}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting an error though ['Out-File' is not recognized as an internal or external command]. Maybe something with escaping the double quotes since i'm passing the entire command enclosed in " to powershell?

Comment: Error : You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-replace' operator. I tried this too `%{$_ -replace '`",`"(\w+?=)','`",`$1`"'}` , the error went off but replacement didnt happen

Comment: You have to use single quotes when calling capture groups like `$1` else the command interpeter might think they are variables and try to expand them.

Comment: @Matt You don't have to, but if you use double quotes you have to escape the $, as I did above.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont think its the $1 thats causing the issue. I tried `%{$_ -replace '","(\w+?\=)', '",X"'}` and that didnt work either..

Comment: I didnt notice the backtick on the $. You are right. @gbzygil My intention was to point it out to other readers. It would not have caused an issue.

Comment: Ok, new approach. Please try my last line of code in place of what you previously had, and see if that provides the desired result.